# Image Path Not Resolved

Tags: plugin, image

I'm transferring my site to a different server.  I'm building out a microsite on Expression Engine 1.6.8.  The issue is the image path is not resolved using the Image Sizer plugin.  Here is an example of a tag:

```
<a href="{global_url}tour/"><h2>{title}</h2>
<img src="{master_site}{exp:imgsizer:size src="{small_img}" 
justurl="yes" width="249" alt=""}" width="249" alt="gator image" class="gator" /></a>
```

What happens is the master_site global variable works, but no path is added for Image Sizer.   So the resulting tag is:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com" width="249" alt="gator image" class="gator">
```

Comment: Probably an environment thing. Dang, you're calling from 2009? Upgrade that situation.

Comment: What do you mean by environment thing?

Comment: You changed servers and are experiencing an issue, that's is indicative of an environment issue. If you still don't understand, comment back and I'll give you an answer explaining what environment means (it's a server engineering).

Comment: Anything that you can add would help.   It seems it's the Image Sizer to me but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm going to guess you're running into an issue where you're moving a site from a server that is running a PHP version in that era (2009ish), and you moved to a server running newer versions of everything (Linux/Windows core, Apache, PHP agent, MySQL, etc...) and some method call in Image Sizer is deprecated completely. I don't jack sh*t about EE 1.X, I so incredibly recommend upgrading to a 2.X version, it hurts. I'm sorry, that's all I can really help you with. Maybe some old wizard can chime in.

Comment: Like, seriously, even though EE hasn't had any major security breaches ever, you are seriously at risk for new 0-days. Please please upgrade, but I do hope someone can help you resolve your current issue.

Comment: Well, the main site works, so it's not EE 1.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you say you're using imagesizer??

Check the permissions and ownership fo the folders where imagesizer is putting its cache. I'll bet its not writable, or owned by someone other than the web executing user (and thus it can not create its directories). Error Reporting can stop the errors appearing properly.

Apart from this, sort those quotes out, as you never know PHP's magic quote settings might have changed or it may be reading differently, like so :

```
<a href="{global_url}tour/">
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  <img src='
    {master_site}
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{small_img}" justurl="yes" width="249" alt=""}
    ' width="249" alt="Assisted Living Facilities Buffalo Grove - Take a tour" class="lifestyle" />
</a>
```

And lastly, jsut output hte path instead of obfuscating it inside the `img` tag. Like so :

```
<a href="{global_url}tour/">
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{small_img}" justurl="yes" width="249" alt=""}
</a>
```

This last test will tell you if its a problem with the images (resizing, mkdir, mv file ect) or with the path itself. i.e. if the path looks good but there's no image on the filesystem this screams write permissions or ownership, if the path is blank but there's a file there its a problem somewhere inside imgsizer. Let us know whats happening, specifically if the images are being created in the right place and if the paths coming out right.

Some last things to check, since the server move has the server path to your root directory changed? i.e. was it `/home/mysite/public_html` and now its `/var/www/vhosts/mysite/htdocs` ? If the answer is Yes, please double check your paths in Content > Files > File Upload Preferences, as these may not have updated...

Also, you have got GD lib installed and activated in PHP/Apache right? without it imgsizer won't be doing no resizing!!!!

Let us know how you fare!!!

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a permissions thing.  I have a main site and a micro site. Going to try .htaccess to manage the subdomains instead of DNS.